# What is the output of the following program? Can anyone explain how the program executes?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
class A implements Runnable{
   int i=0;
   public void run(){
      System.out.println("Thread-"+i++);
   }
}

class Demo {
   public static void main(String []args) {
      A a=new A();
      Thread t1=new Thread(a);
      Thread t2=new Thread(a);
      Thread t3=new Thread(a);
      t1.start();
      t2.start();
      t3.start();
   }
}
```

Can anyone please explain how this code executes and what will be the output?

Comment: Why don't you just run it and try?

Comment: @Simz experimentation does not necessarily lead to understanding. I think this is would be a good on-topic question, would it not be the 1000th incarnation of its kind, making it a clear duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You'd expect the output to be:

```
Thread-0  
Thread-1  
Thread-2
```

But if you own a multi-core machine you'll realize after a couple of runs that it does not always print this result.

If you're wondering why the output is different from the one you were expecting, its because the threads are being run concurrently (at the same time).
Since there is nothing to block threads from incrementing `i` at the same time, it is possible for two or more threads to do the exact same thing at the same time (incrementing `i` from 0 to 1, for instance).

I had to run it a few times to get a concurrent access and got this result:

```
Thread-0
Thread-0
Thread-1
```

Programs like this that can produce several different results are called [nondeterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm). This is a particular case where there is a [data race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (accessing the `i` variable).

A few ways to fix this behavior and get consistent output is to make the `i++` operation *atomic* using lock objects, or use `AtomicInteger` instead of `int`.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why I got a downvote? Did I write something wrong?

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, but I would guess)A good reason for downvoting would be the half sentence `But if you own a multi-threaded machine` as if there is a real-life chance the asker uses some pocket calculator with a _custom single threaded OS_. (I guess you've meant a **multi-core** machine.)

Comment: @mg30rg I will edit that, thank you. Anyway, the chance seems very real to me, take Arulx Z's answer for instance, he even says that the order remains the same.

Comment: I see no problem in your answer after the edit (I would even upvote it if it has the term **"undeterministic"**). Also, I would have downvoted [Arulx Z's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30547944/2144232) if it wasn't already at 0pt.

Answer (score 0):

Output will be

```
Thread-0
Thread-1
Thread-2
```

The order remains the same because they are synced. Check the results online - [IDEone](https://ideone.com/DM0TCi).

Comment: This is a particular case. There is a set of possible results and this is just one of them. `i++` can execute concurrently and will produce several possible outputs. Even though we know what values `i` can have at the end of the execution, we call this a [non-deterministic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm).